# Why Playwright take extra time to finish even though the test has passed?

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

#### Example 1 (visit google.com)

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("example", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
});
```

console:

```
Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 [Microsoft] › google.spec.ts:3:6 › example (2.9s)

  1 passed (4.2s)
```

#### Example 2 (visit baidu.com)

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("example", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.baidu.com");
});
```

console:

```
Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 [Microsoft] › baidu.spec.ts:3:6 › example (1.9s)

  1 passed (9.3s)
```

#### Question

Why does Playwright need extra time to terminate even though the test has passed?

Why it takes ~10 seconds for the second test to finish?

##### Config

Repo: https://github.com/kingyue737/playwright-test

I ran them on Windows 10/11 with built-in Edge. The Playwright version is ^1.39.0.

```js
import type { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";
import { devices } from "@playwright/test";

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  testDir: "./e2e",
  timeout: 30 * 1000,
  expect: {
    timeout: 5000,
  },
  use: {
    actionTimeout: 0,
    headless: false,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Microsoft",
      use: {
        ...devices["Desktop Edge"],
        channel: "msedge",
      },
    },
  ],
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply here, but I can answer this for you.

Your dummy tests show different times due to how playwrights `await page.goto()` method works.

This method is clearly asynchronous, and will navigate to the supplied URL. But, it will wait for the load state that is fired on opening to complete also.

The time may never be the same in your tests, even if the same URL is used, as this load event that is awaited includes scripts that may run, images loading, styling etc.

Without this added benefit to this method, navigation could get quite flakey indeed.

As for the overall termination times, this is trickier to diagnose. These could be related to browser policies, OS specific issues, or even the worker process that maybe be shared in something like sharding.